# Hanging java Process on solaris

Tags: java, solaris, freeze

We have a problem where our java process is  hanging forever,
Unless a Kill -9 is issued against it.

The same Process is running successfully in the Other Solaris Envs,

Java process consist single thread which starts and end after doing some processing On the Data ,Though from the logs and data we can see that the code is completely executed and all the data is processed.

but if we do JPS we will always see that process is  running.
we are Using EHcache with spring for caching purpose and UCP for the connection pool.
On The dB side we Have ORACLE RAC Structure.

took several Jstacks and can never See the Process sticking in the my code.
though from thread dump can see there are lot of UCP threads hanging there.

Also Adding a Shutdown hook  and removing It in the end,but some reason seems the shutdownhook is never called.

Due to project restrictions ,cant paste the code.

can Anyone Please help

Comment: I think you can edit the code so It doesn't even look anymore like the code it was AND you would still be able to show us what you mean. It will make it much more clear.

Comment: Also, note that a shutdown hook is only run when the JVM exits normally or is interrupted in response to user input.  "Hanging" and `kill -9` are neither of these cases, so you wouldn't expect your hooks to run.

Comment: have to issue kill -9 as JVM is never exiting normally,

Comment: Can Somebody Please help,As this process works fine on The other ENVs and gracefully shuts down So cant suspect the Code.can somebody suggest .

Comment: hi @YashChaudhry, are u able to found out the root cause? i got the similar issue..do you have any solution? thank you.

Answer (score -1):

my customer is facing same problem with our installer hanging on Solaris. when installer ran in debug mode, we realized that java which is embedded with installer is hanging.  Please post in case any of you found answer for it.

Comment: This is not an answer. At most this is a comment.

Comment: true. I was not able to add comment on above.